# QT with MSVC2015 trigger multiple compilation errors

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

Trying to update our project from Qt5.6 on MSVC2013 to Qt5.6 on MSVC2015, I got an endless list of error:

- C2059
- C2143
- C2447
- C2059

All of them seem related to lines of type:

```
Q_DECLARE_SHARED( WhateverHere )
```

We make a new install on several machines and all of them has the same issue.

The question is: What is the reason of those errors? What is the solution to this issue?

Comment: May you provide me some information about `Q_DECLARE_SHARED`? Searched the docs and the web but found not much.

Comment: @maxik: More info here: https://0bin.net/paste/Y4sxeVJ5KQmoy8vi#GN5LEO4eIdEP5tCtF-iYvPK1NKLL6HQjbWwhR/DhlvS , which is taken from qtbase\src\corelib\global\qtypeinfo.h

Comment: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2012-July/005205.html

Comment: @maxik: You are right, Q_DECLARE_SHARED is used internally in Qt headers somehow.
(at)Drop:Your link seem unrelated, as now involving MSVC2015. I should have full up-to-date headers as downloaded today from qt.io.

Comment: What are you asking about? Compiling Qt itself? - If so, then you must show exactly how to reproduce this issue, starting from a clean command prompt (Cmd-R cmd). Otherwise, if this is about compiling your project - How are you compiling it? Have you made a new build folder for your project? Do you have a version of Qt compiled using VS2015? Etc. - it is not clear at all what you've done nor what are you trying to do.

Comment: Is about compiling our own project (not QT), which link to QT. This is compiling for MSVC9, 10, 12, but MSVC14 show those errors in Qt headers. From my last checks, It seem related with QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

After some further research, it seem that I had some compatibility code like:

```
#ifdef _MSVC_DEV
#define noexcept throw() //not exactly the same
#endif
```

As `MSVC2015` include now `noexcept`, this macro become invalid. Instead of showing a correct error there, this trigger some strange state in the compiler which then throw errors in `Qt` code.